# Im trying to get the last record submitted in the db using the repository pattern and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to get the last record submitted in the db using the repository pattern and MVC. I am attaching the interface and class.And the controller where you can put the code. Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

```
public interface IRequestRepository
{
    tblRequest GetCaseId(int caseId);     
}

public class RequestRepository: IRequestRepository
{
    helpdeskEntities context = null;
    public RequestRepository()
    {
        context = new helpdeskEntities();
    }
    public string GetCaseId(Ticket ticket)
    {
        string caseId = string.Empty;

        tblRequest tr = context.tblRequests.Where(u => u.CaseID == ticket.CaseID && u.UEmailAddress == ticket.UEmailAddress).SingleOrDefault();


        if (tr != null)
        {
            caseId = tr.CaseID;
        }

        return caseId;
    }

}

    public class Ticket
   {
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ULastName { get; set; }
    //public string UDisplayName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UDep_Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UEmailAddress { get; set; }
    //public string UComputerName { get; set; }
    //public string UIPAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProbCat { get; set; }
    //public string IniDateTime { get; set; }
    //public string UpdateProbDetails { get; set; }
    //public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string InitiatedBy_tech { get; set; }
    public string AssignedBy { get; set; }
    public string TechAssigned { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ProbDetails { get; set; }


}



Controller
 public ActionResult CreateTicket(tblRequest td)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Implement the IRequestRepository interface in your RequestRepository class. Having Ticket as argument in GetCaseId method is not what interface declares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to upgrade your IRequestRepository and add that method:
(I am assuming you're using EntityFramework for that)

```
   public IRequestRepository 
   {
       Request Latest(Ticket ticket);
   }
```

Next, you need to implement that method in your `RequestRepository`:

```
   public class RequestRepository : IRequestRepository
   {
        /* other code here */

        public Request Latest(Ticket ticket)
        {
           // I'm also assuming you're using an auto incremented CaseId
           return this.context.tblRequests.OrderByDescending(p => p.CaseId).FirstOrDefault(p => p.UEmailAddress == ticket.UEmailAddress);
        }
    }
```

---

And another thing:

Your IRequestRepository.GetCaseId implementation returns a string while it should return a `tblRequest` (one would also expect it to return an int Id...)

Anyway, I hope this helps!